# Matlab: 2D cell array to char array

Tags: matlab, cell-array

I was wondering if there is a nice way in which I can convert my 2D cell array into a 2D char matrix.

The cell array looks like this:

```
'test'    'me'    '0'     '22' 
'tester'  'me'    '14'    '241'
'test'    'you'   '25'    '1'
```

And now I would like to put spaces between the columns and make the whole thing a char array. Meaning I want either this:

```
'test me 0 22    '
'tester me 14 241'
'test you 25 1   '
```

or this

```
'test   me  0   22'
'tester me  14 241'
'test   you 25   1'
```

Could you help me out?
I tried `char()` but it doesn't care that the cell array is 2D and just creates one row for each element in the cell array.

**EDIT:** In case someone wants to get back a cell array of the concatenated rows look at this [Combine Columns of Cell Array Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22418191/combine-columns-of-cell-array-matlab)

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, `char` gets you part of the way there, and some mucking about with reshape etc. does the rest:

```
out = char(C');
out(:,end+1)=' ';
out = reshape(out',[28,3]);
out = out';
```

(has perhaps more spaces in than you wanted)

However, a better way might be to pad the internal strings in the cell array so the total length is the same in each row, then add

```
f = @(x) [x,' '];
% need at least one space after each entry
C = cellfun(f,C,'UniformOutput',0); 
% now work out how much extra length needed
l = cellfun(@length,C);
l = sum(l,2);
l = max(l)-l;
% pad
for n = 1:length(l)
    C{n,end} = [C{n,end},blanks(l(n))];
end
```

Now all we need is:

```
cell2mat(C)

ans =

test me 0 22      
tester me 14 241  
test you 25 1
```

Comment: Yes that would work, thanks :) Was still hoping for something cleaner without a loop, hehe.

Answer (score 1):

I can only see how to do it while matching the format specified with a simple loop, if format is not important using char and reshape as nkjt did is the best I can see...

```
cellArray={ snip };

outp=[]

for ii=1:size(cellArray,2)
outp=[outp str2mat(cellArray(:,ii)) blanks(size(cellArray,1))'];
end
```

works column-wise using `str2mat` to concatenate each column into a (padded) char array, adding a trailing space, then adding to the output.

results:

```
outp =

test   me  0  22  
tester me  14 241 
test   you 25 1
```